# How to get .crt file from .jks

Tags: java, tomcat, https, ssl-certificate, jks

I need to make my website SSL configured. I have the following files with me:
file.csr and
file.jks

and I need the following files to SSL enable my website:
file.crt and 
file.key and
keystore

I have searched through the internet but found no help regarding. Can anyone tell me how I can get these files using the files I already have?

I have tried multiple options for conversion but nothing worked.

```
<Connector port="8442" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
keystoreFile="/conf/keys/server/keystore"
               keystorePass="CHANGEME"/>
```

Comment: Have you considered searching through the Tomcat documentation? instead of the entire Internet? It's all in there.

Comment: i have got the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Following are the commands I performed to get the desire result

Convert mobiliser.jks file to keystore.p12:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mobiliser.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Convert keystorep.12 file to keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

Create key:

```
C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out mobiliser.key
```

Create certificate:

```
C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nokeys -out mobiliser.crt
```