# How to connect to kafka using xk6-kafka when I have *-keystore.jks & *-truststore.jks?

Tags: apache-kafka, jks, k6

I am trying to connect to kafka to eventually load test a kafka consumer by producing messages. But I am not sure how to connect to the consumer using *.jks files.

Code snippet:

```
    const saslConfig = {
    algorithm: SASL_SSL
};

// TLS config is optional
const tlsConfig = {
    enableTls: true,
    insecureSkipTlsVerify: true,
    clientCertPem: "<certificate_from_keystore_jks>.pem",
    clientKeyPem: "<key_from_keystore_jks>.pem",
    serverCaPem: "<CACert_from_keystore_jks>.pem",
};

const writer = new Writer({
    brokers: <bootstrapServers>,
    topic: <kafkaTopic>,
    sasl: saslConfig,
    tls: tlsConfig,
});
const connection = new Connection({
    address: <bootstrapServer>,
    sasl: saslConfig,
    tls: tlsConfig,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the tests for how auth works. [`xk6-kafka` uses `segmentio/kafka-go`](https://github.com/mostafa/xk6-kafka/blob/main/auth_test.go)

You need to extract `cer` and/or `pem` files from the JKS files since those are only for JVM libraries.

Related

- [How to get .crt file from .jks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053264/how-to-get-crt-file-from-jks)
- [Convert java keystore (.jks format) file to public format (.pem / .cer) file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353415/convert-java-keystore-jks-format-file-to-public-format-pem-cer-file-typ)

Alternatively, you could look into tools like JMeter for load testing, which are Java-based, or Kafka's own included `kafka-producer-perf-test` tool.

Comment: I used this...but still no luck. I am still getting: "Failed to create dialer., OriginalError: %!w(*fmt.wrapError=&{could not successfully authenticate to <kafka_host_name>". I have edited the question to include the code I have written.

Comment: On a side note, what you described in your answer, works perfectly with kafka-python. But k6 is what has been decided as the official load test tool here!

Comment: I'm not sure. I suggest creating a github issue